# Outer drop shadow in complex SVG [jVectorMap Countries]

Tags: css, svg, jvectormap, dropshadow, svg-filters

I have added drop shadow in some countries of jVectorMap.

Filter used for drop shadow:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="f2" x="0" y="0">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="0" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
    </filter>

    <filter id = "i1">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx = "0" dy = "0"/>
      <feColorMatrix result="matrixOut" in="offOut" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="4"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

> Example: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/sahasovon/pen/WvPMLr)

It looks fine for big countries. But the problem is for small countries. **For small countries, the shadow is creating a square shape around the border** (zoom in for countries like Kosovo and Aland in the example).

How can I remove that square shape to make it looks alike other big countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand your filter region and you'll be fine:

```
<filter id = "i1" x="-40%" y="-40%" width="180%" height="180%">
```

does it for me.